# Jupyter Dropdown ipywidget displays wrong dataframe

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am well and truly baffled. First time using the dropdown widget so forgive me if this is obvious and thank you for any help you can provide.
Here is the dataframe I want to display and how it was built:

```
def top_10_venues(data) :
    num_top_venues = 10
    indicators = ['st', 'nd', 'rd']

# create columns according to number of top venues
    columns = ['Neighborhood']
    for ind in np.arange(num_top_venues):
        try:
            columns.append('{}{} Most Common Venue'.format(ind+1, indicators[ind]))
        except:
            columns.append('{}th Most Common Venue'.format(ind+1))

# create a new dataframe
    neighborhoods_venues_sorted = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
    neighborhoods_venues_sorted['Neighborhood'] = data['Neighborhood']

    for ind in np.arange(denver_grouped.shape[0]):
        neighborhoods_venues_sorted.iloc[ind, 1:] = return_most_common_venues(data.iloc[ind, :], num_top_venues)

    neighborhoods_venues_sorted = neighborhoods_venues_sorted.set_index(['Neighborhood'])
top_10_venues(denver_grouped)
neighborhoods_venues_sorted
```

[image: This is what I want to see]

Here is my dropdown widget:

```
#Experimenting with Jupyter dropdown

filtered_df = None


dropdown = widgets.SelectMultiple(
                        options=neighborhoods_venues_sorted.index,
                        description='Venue',
                        disabled=False,
                        layout={'height':'100px', 'width':'40%'})

def max_density(widget):
    global filtered_df
    selection = list(widget['new'])

    with out:
        clear_output()
        display(neighborhoods_venues_sorted[selection])
        filtered_df = neighborhoods_venues_sorted[selection]

out = widgets.Output()
dropdown.observe(filter_dataframe, names='value')
display(dropdown)
display(out)
```

Here is what I end up seeing, the unformatted dataframe I ran the function on?

[image: Why???]

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand what you want as the result, compared to what you are getting. Within your max_density function, add a `print(selection)` statement and show the result? Please make your code copy-paste-runnable, can you create the dataframe from a dictionary etc?

Comment: Will do, thanks for the input. I don't understand why the output of denver_neighnorhoods_sorted by itself is the dataframe with sorted columns, and the dataframe output by the drop-down is not the same?

Answer (score 0):

Booyah, figured it out!
Seems my issue was a misunderstanding of what was happening within the cell that created neighborhoods_venues_sorted. I thought I was creating a dataframe. Instead I created a function

First is the sort function

```
def return_most_common_venues(row, num_top_venues):
    row_categories = row.iloc[1:]
    row_categories_sorted = row_categories.sort_values(ascending=False)
    
    return row_categories_sorted.index.values[0:num_top_venues]
```

This is the new function instead of a block of code in a cell

```
#Function to create sorted data frame with top 10 most common venues

def top_ten_venues(df) : 
    num_top_venues = 10
    indicators = ['st', 'nd', 'rd']
    
    # create columns according to number of top venues
    columns = ['Neighborhood']
    for ind in np.arange(num_top_venues):
        try:
            columns.append('{}{} Most Common Venue'.format(ind+1, indicators[ind]))
        except:
            columns.append('{}th Most Common Venue'.format(ind+1))
    
    neighborhoods_venues_sorted = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
    neighborhoods_venues_sorted['Neighborhood'] = df['Neighborhood'] 
    
    for ind in np.arange(denver_grouped.shape[0]):
        neighborhoods_venues_sorted.iloc[ind, 1:] = return_most_common_venues(df.iloc[ind, :], num_top_venues)
    #important to have a return in a function, this is the output that can be attached to a variable
    return neighborhoods_venues_sorted
```

Next I ran it on my targeted dataframe and assigned it to a variable. This fixed my issue, I'm still too new to understand fully why when this exact same code was run in a cell it refused to assign it as a new dataframe.

```
#creating a variable to hold the df for later access
neighborhoods_venues_sorted = top_ten_venues(denver_grouped)
#reindexing because it's fun
neighborhoods_venues_sorted = neighborhoods_venues_sorted.set_index(['Neighborhood'])
```